# Patch method blocked by Cors

Tags: javascript, laravel, cors

I have a website with JS on front and Laravel/Lumen for the back.
I have some GET and POST request with fetch, all are working fine (on localhost and on production), but I have a CORS error just for the PATCH request, on production env.

The error on Firefox:

[Cors error Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgSod.png)

The preflight is ok,

[Preflight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub2M3.png)

but not the actual request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S3iJ.png)

In front, i configure the fetch options as below :

```
  getFetchOptions: function (method, dataToSend) {

    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    let fetchOptions = {
        "method": method,
        "mode": "cors",
        "cache": "no-cache",
        "headers": myHeaders,
        "body": JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
    };

    return fetchOptions;
},
```

and in back, i have a cors middleware configured as below :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

     if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
        $response = response('', 200);
    }

    $response
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://todolist.severinebianchi.com')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

    return $response;
}
```

}

I tried to add headers in `.htaccess`, in `index.php`, but nothing was working and i don't understand why?

My .htaccess

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://todolist.severinebianchi.com"                   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE" 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
```

Comment: Did you set the [Accept-Patch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Patch) header?

Comment: How and where do you set this response header ? I didn't find so much infos about it...

Comment: You could try setting this on the server, `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH'); ?>`

Comment: I already have a .htaccess with :
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://todolist.severinebianchi.com"                   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE" 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"

Comment: Do you have the same error on Chrome?

Comment: No, in Chrome i have a "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error

Comment: @SevB I'm not sure my solution. First, you remove all in `.htaccess`. Second, in `handle` function, you replace `->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');` by `->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');`. Let me know the results when you try. Merci!

Comment: No, i have the same message "CORS request did not succeed " :/

Comment: @SevB  Do you have to use `"mode": "cors",` in your request?

Comment: I've tried to remove that option but it didn't change anything

Comment: @SevB Do you use `OPTIONS` method in your request?

Comment: Yes, and the preflight is ok in network

Comment: In `handle()` function. did you try to add `OPTIONS` into `->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')`?

Comment: Yes, i did but no change :o

Comment: @SevB C'est bizarre! I think I need more time to find the solution. Désolé!

Comment: @SevB Did you try to add `\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class` in `Kernel.php`?. Reference: https://www.mynotepaper.com/easiest-way-to-allow-cors-in-laravel

Comment: @SevB How's the situation?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. It seems that it could be a problem with my host so i use a put request instead of a patch one, and it's ok. Thanks for your help btw :)